# Dot Net Core Web API deploy to Linux - does not return any response (json)

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to run dot net core 5 web api application in Red hat linux 8 server.
I created sample web api application “webapp3” using Visual Studio 2019 (weather app) on local windows10 ,  using dot net 5 and tested, it works fine. It returns the json response.
Then I published the application to a local folder

Then I configured a new EC2 RHEL 8 instance in AWS , installed dot net core 5
Also, created folder /var/www/html and used below command to make ec2-user owner of the folder

```
sudo chown -R -v ec2-user /var/www
```

Using scp copied the published folder from local windows folder to /var/www/html folder in the ec2 instance

Then from /var/www/html folder in the server, ran following command in putty terminal

```
dotnet webapp3.dll
```

The application started properly

Then I opened a duplicate terminal in putty and ran below command

```
curl http://localhost:5000
```

But the command returned nothing and returned to the prompt
Any idea why this is not returning the json response from the web api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. I needed to add weatherforecast in the url , i.e. localhost:5000/weatherforecast